How to evaluate Ginsh in Plot3D
I have a function F[x,y] containing multiple polylogarithms $G$ that can be evaluated numerically via GiNaC within the command Ginsh.
If say (toy example),
F[x,y] := x^2y^2*G[0,xy]

then Ginsh[F[x,y],{x->-50,y->-50}] is simply a number.
How can I use F[x,y] within the Plot3D routine to plot the surface over the range $-50<x<0$, $-50<y<0$? The issue is that Ginsh already produces a number while the Plot3D command expects an expr which is subsequently evaluated between the given variable boundaries.

Do you mean something like Plot3D[Ginsh[F[x,y],{x->-x0,y->-y0}],{x0,-50,50},{y0,-50,50}]?

Thanks, yes I guess so. I had tried Plot3D[Ginsh[F[x,y], {x-> a, y -> b}], {a, -50, 0}, {b, -50, 0},
AxesLabel -> {“xx”, “yy”, “F(xx,yy)”}] but the output didn’t look correct so I thought it was a problem of giving a non-numerical value, i.e. in my case a,b, to Ginsh. I will check this more.

It should work if Ginsh[..] yields a number. I don't have Ginsh[] installed, so I can't check. (Sorry about the typos in my comment. Should read x -> x0 and y -> y0, similar to your code. )
